# Excluding dependencies from javafx maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I'm trying to use the maven shade plugin to make a cross platform fat jar for JavaFX.

The shade plugin part works fine. It runs off of the `package` goal, and it bundles the far jar properly.

The fat jar requires dependency classifiers to load in the appropriate platforms binary artifacts (shared libraries).

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        <classifier>win</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        <classifier>linux</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        <classifier>mac</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

That all works fine.

The problem is that I (i.e. the IDE) normally use the `javafx-maven-plugin` to run and debug the project. And when I have the classified dependencies in the pom, and try to run the project (i.e. mvn javafx:run) I get an exception: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found`.

So, I'm looking to somehow make the classified dependencies conditional. The shade plugin has the ability to include and exclude artifacts, but I don't see a similar thing for the javafx plugin. And it seems that the shade plugin relies on the global dependency list, so I don't see a way to add dependencies solely for the shade plugin. I also don't see an appropriate scope I could perhaps leverage to specify a dependency only for the `package` goal.

Perhaps that's the wrong approach, but that's what I've come up with so far.

Otherwise I'm considering simply having two separate poms to handle this. Perhaps that's the real solution.

Comment: maybe not an optimal solution, but you could use maven profiles to specify either to use the javafx-maven-plugin with the necessary dependencies or the shade plugin with another set of dependencies (and of course you put the common dependencies outside the profiles). It is near to having to poms, but a bit more compact.

Comment: Creating such a super-fat jar is not a recommended practice. Why do you want to do that at all?

Comment: I wonder if you have the correct classifier for whatever OS architecture you are developing on.  For instance if you are using an M1 mac, the classifier is not `mac`, which is only for intel macs, instead it is [`mac-aarch64`](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/18.0.1/).  I linked the maven central repository which contains all of the artifacts with all of the classifiers, you are missing some.  Some are supporting jars like doc and sources, or the monocle headless framework, but others are needed for different target platforms if you want to support them.

Comment: @mipa if you have a mechanic to produce a cross-platform binary that doesn't require to be built on their respective environments, I'm all ears. I don't have a way to build on Windows or M1. I don't consider an external JRE to be a big deal.

Comment: @jewelsea "I linked the maven central repository..." What link is that? I used the sample from the FX website where they discuss the different packaging options, clearly it needs to be updated. But, thanks, I had not considered the M1. Below my radar.

Comment: The [`mac-aarch64`](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/18.0.1/) link is to JavaFX 18.0.1 artifacts in the Maven central repository. They are the jars downloaded through the classified dependency mechanism that you are using in Maven.

Comment: @WillHartung You could do that via GitHub actions with different runners. The tutorial project https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX has the workflows defined already for you.

Comment: @jewelsea Ah, thank you. I didn't realize the link was an actual link. My IDE auto complete for the classifier also lists 2 linux arm version, and a win-x86 (I assume that's 32 bit). I won't include those now, but see if I get requests for them. Thanks though, this was helpful.

Comment: @mipa that looks interesting, I'll look into it, thank you. Another rabbit hole to dig into to try and get this thing into the hands of strangers. The Free Tier looks ample for a hobby project.

Comment: "if you have a mechanic to produce a cross-platform binary that doesn't require to be built on their respective environments, I'm all ears" -> see the [JavaFX tag Packaging](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info) info, one option it provides is a link to [jdeploy.com](https://www.jdeploy.com), which is a service for creating multi-platform binaries for Java applications, including JavaFX apps.  It may not be what you are looking for, but that is one option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put this dependency in [profile](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) in your `pom.xm` file.
And active when needed.